# Comparing Bytes to Hex?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, arrays, hex

I need to compare the first 5 bytes of a UDP packet to two definitions, and act on them accordingly if it matches one. However, how should I represent the Hex for this since this obviously won't/isn't working?

The commented lines are the original way I was doing it, but not very efficient.

```
private static void HandleQuery(Socket socket, EndPoint Remote)
{
    byte[] A2S_INFO_REQUEST = StringToByteArray("\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54");
    byte[] A2S_PLAYER = StringToByteArray("\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55");

    byte[] data = new byte[1400];
    int recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

    // A2S_INFO QUERY
    //if (recv == 25 && data[4] == 84)
    if (CompareByteArray(A2S_INFO_REQUEST, data, 5))
    {
        ReplyInfoQuery(socket, Remote);
    }

    // A2S_PLAYER QUERY
    //if (recv == 9)
    if (CompareByteArray(A2S_PLAYER, data, 5))
    {
        ReplyPlayerQuery(socket, Remote);
    }
}

private static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}

private static bool CompareByteArray(byte[] a1, byte[] a2, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: First, why not just create your arrays like this: `new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x54}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill a byte array easier:

```
//byte[] A2S_PLAYER = StringToByteArray("\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55");
byte[] A2S_PLAYER = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x55} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to convert your 5 bytes in a long (System.Int64). That way you can even use a switch/case to dispatch your requests.