# convert string to byte array

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Is it possbile to convert the content of a string in exactly the same way to a byte array?

For example: I have a string like:

```
string strBytes="0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89";
```

Is there any function which can give me the following result if  i pass strBytes to it.

```
Byte[] convertedbytes ={0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89};
```

Comment: This _question_ contains a function to do exactly that. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6889400/60761

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way, but you can use LINQ to do that:

```
byte[] convertedBytes = strBytes.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                .Select(str => Convert.ToByte(str, 16))
                                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sensible to space after the comma

Comment: @sll, indeed, though the formatting in the questioner's code looks strict enough. However, copying the fix from your answer wouldn't be fair, would it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string strBytes="0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89";

string[] toByteList = strBytes.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires);

byte[] converted = new byte[toByteList.Length];

for (int index = 0; index < toByteList.Length; index++)
{
    converted[index] = Convert.ToByte(toByteList[index], 16);//16 means from base 16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strBytes = "0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89";

IEnumerable<byte> bytes = strBytes.Split(new [] {','}).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x.Trim(), 16));
```